# Azure VSO Continuous Delivery: Deploy specific site in multi-site solution

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We have a VSO repository with multiple sites in the same solution. We want to be able to deploy our sites independently of each other to Azure with continuous delivery. Right now the first site alphabetically is deployed to all our sites which of course is not desirable.

Is this possible to achieve?

I have tried to set the Project key to the correct csproj in App Settings like suggested here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments without any success. Maybe Kudu is not used for VSO?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using a CI server?

Comment: We are using the CI builds automatically set up by Azure in Visual Studio Online when we connect our repo to our sites

Comment: Are you deploying to an Azure Website or a Cloud Service?

Comment: We are deploying to Azure Websites

Answer (score 0):

You should move away from trying to do this in a build, especially if you want that level of control.

You have Release Management Online provided with your VSO account and can use the Release Management client to configure your releases.

I believe that you can right-click on your Build and have an appropriate starter release template created when configured.

http://nakedalm.com/create-release-management-pipeline-professional-developers/

Here is an example of and end to end deployment with a web app. Deploying to Azure with RM is Childs play...